# qtbot in pytest-qt raising AttributeError

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pytest, pytest-qt

OS: W10
Python: 3.10
pytest: 7.3.1
pytest-qt: 4.2.0

It's some time since I've used the `qtbot` fixture. I have what I believe to be a simple setup here. In this code I have included the `qtbot` fixture in the test function:

```
def test_is_possible_to_log_a_message(qtbot):
    ...
    index_0_2 = log_table_view.model().createIndex(0, 2)
    with qtbot.wait(100):
        text_0_2 = log_table_view.model().data(index_0_2)
    assert ...
```

This is causing the following error:

```
>       with qtbot.wait(100):
E       AttributeError: __enter__
```

... I can't see any sign of others experiencing this with pytest-qt. Anyone got any ideas what the problem might be?

**Update**
I was also getting a (more familiar) error when I instead used `waitUntil` (by the way, here, following a signal being emitted, I'm waiting for some text to appear in a cell of a `QTableView`):

```
def text_obtained():
    text_0_2 = log_table_view.model().data(index_0_2)
    print(f'text_0_2 |{text_0_2}|')
    assert text_0_2 != None 
    
qtbot.waitUntil(text_obtained)
```

I *was* getting, on the first call to `text_obtained`:

```
>       text_0_2 = log_table_view.model().data(index_0_2)
E       RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type LogTableView has been deleted
```

... but I've now found that by calling `show()` on my `QMainWindow` (NB nothing appears as I'm using `QT_QPA_PLATFORM = offscreen`) and by using `waitUntil` for elements to become visible, this no longer happens.

However, the `AttributeError` is still happening on `wait`...

Comment: The `__enter__` attribute error indicates that you're trying to use an object as a context manager, but the object doesn't provide such interface. In fact, there is no mention about that possibility in the [`wait()` documentation](https://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#pytestqt.qtbot.QtBot.wait). The second error is common for destroyed Qt objects that are still referenced in python, but without proper MRE we cannot tell you much more.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I'll do an MRE in due course if I can't find out how to get the thing working.

Comment: If you get the thing working, you will not need the MRE anymore.